# Ошибка при добавлении дочернего view в RecyclerView, как исправить?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Делаю раскрывающийся список, вот код. Предполагаю, что ошибка связана с LayoutInflater но не могу разобраться - как сделать правильно

```
public class CompRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CompRVAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    CardView cardView;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CompRVAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_comp, parent, false);
        View child_view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_child_1, parent, true);
        return new ViewHolder(view, child_view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CompRVAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 15;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public ViewHolder(View itemView, View childView) {
            super(itemView);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv1);
            CardView childCardView = (CardView) childView.findViewById(R.id.child_cv);
            LinearLayout linearLayout_childItems = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_linear_layout);

            for (int indexView = 0; indexView < 3; indexView++) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                linearLayout_childItems.addView(childCardView, layoutParams);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    }
}
```

Вот текст ошибки

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4417)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4258)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4230)
        at ru.human_factors.characterist.adapters.CompRVAdapter$ViewHolder.<init>(CompRVAdapter.java:44)
        at ru.human_factors.characterist.adapters.CompRVAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(CompRVAdapter.java:22)
        at ru.human_factors.characterist.adapters.CompRVAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(CompRVAdapter.java:13)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6685)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5869)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3529)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4082)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:443)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:726)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2346)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2068)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: у child_view при раздувании 3 параметр - true. из-за него и ошибка скорее всего, попробуйте на false сменить

Comment: не помогает изменение на false

Comment: согласен - должно помочь, обновите код. Либо проблема на второй итерации цикла внутри ViewHolder, то есть вы пытаетесь второй раз добавить ту же самую вьюху в тотже самый лейяут.